# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'socialMediaOption' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am getting the following JavaScript error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'socialMediaOption' of undefined
>
> - at Function.getBackgroundOptions (content.js:2)
> - at async Function.main (content.js:2)

The error appears in a file named: content.js which appears to be part of chrome-extension, here is the screenshot from chrome dev tools:

[image]

*I don't get this error in FireFox or Edge.*

Comment: The question isn't really answerable. You can report the problem to the extension's author or you can debug the extension's code.

Comment: @wOxxOm: I agree, this is more of a bug report... however I thought someone else might have come across it...